# Unexpected result RangeInclusive<>::all()

Tags: rust

I got a following the section rust code that expect to check 'range_a: RangeInclusive<>' including 'range_b:RangeInclusive<>' or vice versa. I'm not sure how it works and return wrong result in some cases. Could someone explain it?

```rust
fn contains_range(mut range_a: RangeInclusive<u32>, mut range_b: RangeInclusive<u32>) -> bool {
    range_b.all(|i| range_a.contains(&i)) || range_a.all(|i| range_b.contains(&i))
}

fn main() {
     dbg!(contains_range(15..=16, 15..=73));
}
```

I guess the problem'd be `RangeInclusive<>::all()` but if it was, then compiler should have warnings at `RangeInclusive<>::contains()`.

Answer (score 4):

If you sprinkle `dbg` calls everywhere, you will notice that calling `range_b.all` advances `range_b`, so that by the time you reach the second test `range_b` has become  `18..=73`:

```
use std::ops::RangeInclusive;

fn contains_range(mut range_a: RangeInclusive<u32>, mut range_b: RangeInclusive<u32>) -> bool {
    range_b.all(|i| range_a.contains(&i)) || range_a.all(|i| dbg!(dbg!(&range_b).contains(&dbg!(i))))
}

fn main() {
     dbg!(contains_range(15..=16, 15..=73));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8db2046235d4fcd39dd52f707c969876)

gives:

```
[src/main.rs:4] &range_b = 18..=73
[src/main.rs:4] i = 15
[src/main.rs:4] dbg!(& range_b).contains(&dbg!(i)) = false
[src/main.rs:8] contains_range(15..=16, 15..=73) = false
```

The solution is to clone the range before calling `all`:

```
use std::ops::RangeInclusive;

fn contains_range(range_a: RangeInclusive<u32>, range_b: RangeInclusive<u32>) -> bool {
    range_b.clone().all(|i| range_a.contains(&i)) || range_a.clone().all(|i| range_b.contains(&i))
}

fn main() {
     dbg!(contains_range(15..=16, 15..=73));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=80550e728c4d0e4990bf1ea8fd8e09e9)

Comment: that's good solution, but I expect we should have some compiler errors. Could you explain ```.all()``` in detail?

Comment: Why would you expect a compiler error? [`Iterator::all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all) takes `self` by mutable reference which is a strong indication that it advances the iterator, and it is explicitly documented to be short-circuiting (i.e. it stops as soon as the comparison fails)

Comment: I agree with your comment; however, because ```all()``` advances the iterator itself , in the next expression code ```range_b.contains()``` compiler should tell me something.

Comment: probably compiler tell me some warnings at 'contains()' that would be better

Comment: another question come up, it seems to me `Iterator::all` should take `self` as immutable reference maybe?

Comment: @cat916 You have the wrong notion of how iterators work. The `Iterator` trait is built around the idea that a `next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item>` method advances the iterator one step at a time. `All` is no exception here, so checking each item will advance the iterator one by one. And, no, the compiler should not issue a warning here, since it is valid code that may even be useful in edge cases where you *want* the side-effect of an advanced iterator. tl;dr: Iteration *changes* the iterator's state.

Comment: ah I see, I missed understood the concept enumerator and iterator. In C# land, enumerator is a special form of iterator and read only container.